# Binding separate list into one listbox

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, listbox, windows-phone

I want to bind my listbox with separate list data that I get from json web service, so it looks like this:

```
public List<Phone> phone { get; set; }
public List<Fax> fax { get; set; }
public List<Email> email { get; set; }
public List<Website> website { get; set; }
```

and I want to bind all that list into one single listbox, so my listbox will have phone,fax,email and website in one item... how to do that?

edit: example of the format that i have in mind

> phone: +04532534534
>
> fax : +5234523453
>
> email : user@user.com
>
> website : www.user.com

edit: my approach so far is getting putting separated list into separated property into my mainviewmodel

```
RootObjectDetail result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectDetail>(e.Result);
if (result.contacts.email != null)
    hereRestEmail = new ObservableCollection<Email>(result.contacts.email);
if (result.contacts.phone != null)
    hereRestPhone = new ObservableCollection<Phone>(result.contacts.phone);
if (result.media.reviews.items != null)
    hereRestReview = new ObservableCollection<ItemReview>(result.media.reviews.items);
if (result.media.images.items != null)
    hereRestImage = new ObservableCollection<ItemImage>(result.media.images.items);
```

but i just don't know how to bind it into my listbox datacontex since i only can bind one of thos property

```
 <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox
   x:Name="ContactListBox"
   ItemsSource="{Binding hereRestPhone}">
    <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>

          <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.phone,
                      Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>
          <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding value}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />

       </DataTemplate>
     </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

it only can show phone only, i still don't know how to bind fax,email and website into this listbox

Comment: i already edit it into the format that i have in mind for my list, so it will just like that for every item in my list... example is list item 1 and for item 2 and 3 it will just like that but with different value of phone,fax,email,website

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what your classes look like internally, I can only guess:

```
 var allValues =
     phone.Select(x => new { Type = "phone", Value = x.PhoneNumber })
          .Concat(fax.Select(x => new { Type = "fax", Value = x.FaxNumber }))
          .Concat(email.Select(x => new { Type = "email", Value = x.EmailAddr }))
          .Concat(website.Select(x => new { Type = "website", Value = x.URL }))
          .ToList();
```

You'll end up with a list (of anonymous types) with a "Type" and "Value".

I haven't tested this, but you should be able setup a template in your XAML, bind to "Type" and "Value", and get them to display like you've indicated above.

Comment: wow it is syntax that i never seen before... mind to give me reference about this syntax?

Comment: hmmm i think you put wrong link for concat statement since it jump me into the same link as LINQ..., and after reading for a while LINQ is some kind of database/sql so i don't see why this can be use to solve my problem.. maybe you can see my post (already edit) with more detail